# Error con Laravel 5.7 y SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, laravel, sql-server

Al operar con fechas tengo el siguiente problema. EL motor recibe los insert como yyyy-mm-dd pero los update los recibe de la siguiente forma. yyyy-dd-mm generando un problema con eloquent, no se me ocurre como configurarlo para que en los insert utilice un formato y en los update otro.

Utilizo Laravel V. 5.7.27 y SQL server 2012

Comment: no me estas entendiendo. El MOTOR esta configurado de esa manera. (fuera de eloquent recibe las sentencias SQL con esa estructura) por lo tanto, cuando le cambio el formato en el modelo funcionan los INSERT pero no los UPDATE. no tengo como hacer la distincion ya que es el MOTOR el que esta configurado para recibir los insert y update con formatos diferentes

Comment: insisto, es el motor que tiene los formatos distintos para update como para insert. Nose a que se debera, pero con varias BD me pasa lo mismo. Esto utilizando frameworks de microsoft no genera problemas (por ejemplo Entity Framework) el problema es que ELOQUENT de LARAVEL almenos hasta ahora, no he descubierto como cambiarle los formatos segun la operacion. Saludos

Comment: has intentado con la variable `dateformat` en tu modelo de eloquent?